# Email activation is taking me to another page instead

Tags: php

I have the following email activation code and I do have **`activation.php`** in my includes folder but am not sure why it is taking me to another url instead..

```
<a href='https://www.pianocourse101.com/includes/activate.php?email='.$email.'&activatetoken='.$token4.'>Activate your Primer Level here!</a>
```

https://www.pianocourse101.com/includes/index.php?activate=missinglink

It is also showing the following error message:

The requested URL **`/includes/index.php`** was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: It was a syntax issue.. it should be this:

Comment: 'https://www.pianocourse101.com/includes/activate.php?email=$email&activatetoken=$token4'>Activate your Primer Level here!

Comment: You mentioned you have activation.php in includes folder, but the link you posted contains activate.php

Comment: Voting to close because: *It's caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.*